# Authentication using ExpressJS and Angular without PassportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I'm having problem authenticating the users. I'm able to post the users into the MongoDB using Mongoose. But i'm unable to check the users for authentication.

**Express Code:**

```
/* Login User */
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err)
    } else if (!user) {
      var err = new Error('User not found.');
      err.status = 401;
      return callback(err);
    }
    else if (password === user.password) {
      return callback(null, user);
    }
  });
});
```

Please tell me how to authenticate the users and then start the express session.

Comment: This looks incredibly insecure.

Comment: Alex you are absolutely correct. Passwords should not save without encryption. @Surendra Singh Chhabra you can use bCrypt like packages.

Check the final else if part. You have to equate the password in the from the mongodb fetch with `req.body.password` instead of password.

Comment: @AnoopSurendran Thanks! It worked. And also i know that i should use encryption in password, but this was just a simple try. Anyway thanks.